# body margin 8px, unable to change

Tags: website-design, css

[image: screenshot of my website]

The body margin remains 8px by default and I'am unable to change it using CSS. 
Even If body margin is set to 0px in CSS it leaves some space on the top.
What may be the possible solution?

Comment: Your screenshot is showing it has 0px margin...

Comment: Might sounds crazy but... did you check <html> attributes ?

Comment: The problem *isn't* `body`, it's showing it has a padding and margin of `0` (and margins are shown with an orange overlay in devtools). Any top margin on the first visible child of `body` will push it down as it is in your screenshot so I'd guess `#myDiv` has a top margin (but it's hard to tell without seeing the page).

Comment: https://vishnu-dev.github.io/    That is mypage.

Comment: html tag has the size of the page @Vinny

Comment: <div class="thumb"> margin-top should be 0

Comment: Thanks Everyone for helping me out. @Vinny , You're right. But what if I wanted that div to be 100px down?

Comment: @Vishnudev that's what it was doing (`.thumb` is what is enclosing that image of a mac)... What exactly do you want to move 100px down?

Comment: I want only the Image of Mac to be 100px down, not the Logo of the face with it.

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you Cai , Vinny , Vincent for your assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.thumb`, which is the first descendant of `body` that isn't absolutely positioned has a top margin of `100px`, so that is pushing `body` down. Remove that (or set it to `0` or whatever) and that will stop pushing everything down.

[image]

[image]

If you do want to move `.thumb` down without affecting `body`, you can either use padding on `#myDiv` (or `.thumb` itself) instead, or you can set `.thumb` to `display: inline-block;` which aren't affected by collapsing margins.

Comment: But what if I wanted that div (with classname thumb) to be 100px down?

Comment: that's exactly what it was before... (`.thumb` is what is enclosing that image of a mac). What exactly do you want to move 100px down?

Comment: I want only the Image of Mac to be 100px down, not the Logo of the face with it.

Comment: Oh, I see! just add `top: 0;` to the `#myLogo` (it was set to be positioned absolutely but with no explicit position)

Comment: Oh god! Problem solved alas. Thank you @Cai for your guidance.

Comment: No problem, see my update to my answer – setting the position on `#myLogo` doesn't actually fix the issue on `body`, so you may want to change that too

Comment: I have updated my page, Take a look.

Comment: https://vishnu-dev.github.io/

Comment: I see you moved it with `position: relative;` instead. That works, but be aware that if you add anything below, it will be 100px too high! It would be better to use padding instead.